# help negating statements (exclusive or)

Tags: discrete-mathematics, logic, predicate-logic

**I)** All flowers are pink or have a stem.

*(There is at least one flower which isn't pink and doesn't have a stem?)*

**II)** All flowers are either pink or have a stem (exclusive or)

(isn't logical equivalence the negation of the exclusive or?, so would it then be *A flower is pink iff it has a stem?*)

I have posted my thoughts regarding the solutions, would be thankful for advice and correction if needed.

Comment: @T.H.Shehadi thank you so if I negate the exclusive it always isn't it the same as equivalence, so that either both are true or both are false? so the negation would be (there is at least one flower which is pink and have a stem) or there is at least one  flower which is not pink and does not have a stem?

Comment: When you negate the exclusive or, you will get $(p \vee \lnot q) \wedge (\lnot p \vee q)$ which is also equivalent to $(p\wedge q)~\vee~(\neg p\wedge\neg q)$so your statement will be all your flowers are either pink and have a stem or they neither pink nor have a stem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

"Exclusive or" $(p\oplus q)$ can be written as $(p\land\lnot q)\lor(\lnot p\land q)$, where as "if and only if" $(p\leftrightarrow q)$ can be written as $(p\land q)\lor(\lnot p\land\lnot q)$.

And so, it can be seen that $(p\oplus q)$ is equivalent to $(p\leftrightarrow\lnot q)$.

And so $\neg(p\oplus q)$ is equivalent to $(p\leftrightarrow q)$.

[But, be careful using a biconditional in a existential statement.]

Comment: Very complete answer!! Why do we have care using a biconditional in an existential statement if they are equivalent propositions (same truth table)?

Comment: You need to carefully phrase it in English.

Comment: thank you but may I ask, why the negation would be $(p \leftrightarrow \lnot q)$, I can not see this, if I negate the exclusive it always comes back to the equivalence, because exclusive or says exactly one is correct and equivalence say either both are true or both are false? wouldn't that be the negation?  why isn't the negation $(p \leftrightarrow q)$?

Comment: Would the negation in english be "there is at least one flower which is pink and has a stem" and there is at least one flower which isn't pink and does not have a stem?

Comment: typo correckted.